# On rewriting the statement into predicate logic.

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm interested in rewriting mathematical statement into predicate logic.

Is the following correct?

#### Normal Expression

the following $x$ exists, such that $x \in R,x^2-1=0$

#### Predicate Logic Expression

$\exists x(x\in R \space\land x^2-1=0) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct equivalent sentence in first order logic.